# 2 job offers waiting for email

Tags: job-offer

I have recently been offered 2 jobs(my first after graduating from university) and both were over the phone. Job A wanted me to start immediately and thus want a response ASAP. Job B starts later on but they would like a response in a week. Both offered me the position over the phone and Job B said they would email me the morning after(the day of writing this).

Job B is the position I really want, but I would like to have the offer in writing before turning down Job A. As I said Job A want a reply ASAP so I do need to hurry Job B in getting the offer in writing. What would be the best way to get them to expedite their response? I do have their phone and email available.

Comment: I feel I'm less trying to delay it as the post you mentioned more so trying to get Job B to speed up because once I have an email confirmation I will feel a lot more secure. Before turning down Job A

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773

Comment: you could always verbally accept job A tell them you will not be able to start for another week, then if you get job B retract your acceptance.

Answer (score 7):

> I do need to hurry Job B in getting the offer in writing. What would
>   be the best way to get them to expedite their response?

First wait until "the morning after". If you get the expected email from B, then you have nothing left to do but accept.

If you haven't heard from them in a day or so, since B already offered you the job over the phone, you should call them back.

Tell them something like "I want to accept your offer. I'm really excited about working with you, but I really need the offer in writing. I have other offers that I'm holding off, so could you send me the written offer today so I can get back to them quickly? I want to be fair to them. Thanks!"

Company B will almost certainly be able to send you the written offer quickly, or at least give you an indication as to how long it will actually take.

Comment: This.  There is nothing to be lost by showing a potential employer that you have a sense of self-worth.  If you act as if you're worthy of respect, you will garner more respect.

Answer (score 0):

Email or phone company B and request that they make you the offer in writing immediately, as you're getting pressure from company B. Tell company B that you are offering speed in return for speed: if they make you the offer ASAP, you won't be waiting for a week to reply and you'll reply just as fast :)